# ipad camera fullscreen : hide statusbar : return back : mainViewController height increased 20 px

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

my application is a landscape(left and right) mode application.

I am opening camera with full screen mode.
Steps
1. Open Camera (then status bar hidden) and mainviewController height increased 20px
2. Rotate device (from landscape right to left or vice versa)
3. close camera (then status bar come back)

top 20px pmainviewController is covered by statusbar. **(this is my issue)**

If again rotate the device then view height become correct.

Is any way to reset ViewController

**Actual Main View Controller with Status Bar**
[image: Actual Main View Controller with Status Bar]

**Main View Controller after camera with Status Bar**
[image: Main View Controller after camera with Status Bar]

Answer (score 0):

Before showing your camera interface you can hide the status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then when the picker is dismissed show the status bar again.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
```